# avoiding stack overflow when running a recursive timeout

Tags: javascript, node.js

So, i want to run an intervaled function, but with a recursive timeout:

```
var runUpdater = function () {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('something here')
    runUpdater()
  }, 1000)
}
```

this will be running on a service that will be always on for long periods of time. I assume this will eventually come to a stack overflow, am i right? My question is: what is the best way to avoid it?

Comment: There's no recursion in the code -> "Problem" solved :)

Comment: How about `setInterval()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there will not be a stack overflow. Each call to `setTimeout` queues a new message in the event-loop. When the callback to setTimeout is executed you have a whole new stack with depth `1` that will cease to exist when that execution thread completes. For example, the following will quickly throw a RangeError when the maximum stack size is reached:

```js
try {
    !function func ( ) {
        func();
    }();
} catch ( e ) {
    document.body.innerHTML = e.message;
}
```

But this version will run indefinitely without problems:

```js
try {
    !function func ( ) {
        setTimeout( func, 0 );
    }();
} catch ( e ) {
    document.body.innerHTML = e.message;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After a little testing, I don't think there's a recursion with your current code. As `runUpdater()` immediately exits after executing the inner `runUpdater()`. `setTimeout()` call doesn't block the browser's main thread, instead what it does is schedule your function call whenever your browser is idle and then exits immediately (which subsequently terminates the caller, thus no recursion occurs)

I would prefer using `setInterval()` in your case for the sake of readability and avoid any confusion of `recursive` calls:

```
setInterval(function() {
    console.log('something here');
}, 1000);
```

Edit based on comment made by @Paulpro (thanks!):

I assumed `setInterval` does the same with `setTimeout` with delay and calling the same function, but it doesn't, setTimeout runs in sequence and only schedule the next call when your function calls `runUpdater()` whereas `setInterval` just schedules ignoring the state of the function being called

tl;dr: use his version of the answer

Comment: Note that setInterval will cause problems if the code it is running takes longer than the delay between running it (even asynchronously), since it will continue to queue up more and more callbacks and get further and further behind. That can get pretty bad if it is making an Ajax request each time or something. You can easily reach the maximum number of requests your browser will send at once at then build up a large queue on top of that, and if you make any other Ajax requests elsewhere they won't get sent for a long time.